# Type troubles with custom typeclass

Tags: haskell, types, monads

I'm having some trouble with types while learning Haskell.
I have a typeclass called `Stack` which obviously should behave like a stack. I have a type `Elem` which is simply either an Int or a Bool.

Now I want my function to take a `Stack` of `Elem` and do some operations with it. The result is not actually important, however I am failing to even acquire the first element of the stack and I have failed to figure out what is wrong for hours now.

```
import Control.Monad

data Elem = Number Int | Truth Bool deriving Eq

instance Show Elem where
  show (Number i) = show i
  show (Truth b) = show b

class Stack stack where
  push :: a -> stack a -> stack a
  top :: MonadPlus m => stack a -> m (a,stack a)
  empty :: stack a
  isEmpty :: stack a -> Bool

instance Stack [] where
  push a stack = a:stack
  top stack = if isEmpty stack then mzero else return (head stack, tail stack)
  empty = []
  isEmpty stack = if null stack then True else False

step :: Stack stack => String -> stack Elem -> Maybe (stack Elem)
step ex st = let e1 = top st :: Maybe (Elem, stack Elem)
                 --a1 = fmap fst e1
                 --e2 = top (fmap snd e1)
                 --a2 = fmap fst e2
             in Nothing
```

The error I am getting is

```
Playground.hs:22:27:
    Could not deduce (stack ~ stack2)
    from the context (Stack stack)
      bound by the type signature for
                 step :: Stack stack => String -> stack Elem -> Maybe (stack Ele
m)
      at Playground.hs:21:9-65
      `stack' is a rigid type variable bound by
              the type signature for
                step :: Stack stack => String -> stack Elem -> Maybe (stack Elem
)
              at Playground.hs:21:9
      `stack2' is a rigid type variable bound by
               an expression type signature: Maybe (Elem, stack2 Elem)
               at Playground.hs:22:23
    Expected type: stack2 Elem
      Actual type: stack Elem
    Relevant bindings include
      st :: stack Elem
        (bound at Playground.hs:22:9)
      step :: String -> stack Elem -> Maybe (stack Elem)
        (bound at Playground.hs:22:1)
    In the first argument of `top', namely `st'
    In the expression: top st :: Maybe (Elem, stack Elem)
```

I really fail to see why Haskell refuses this (and even refuses simply calling `top st` in my function without me trying to specify a type).

I hope someone can shed some light on this!

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that the `stack` in the type sig of `step` is the same `stack` in `Maybe (Elem, stack Elem)`.  You're looking for `ScopedTypeVariables`, but it means you'll have to change the sig to `step :: forall stack. Stack stack => String -> stack Elem -> Maybe (stack Elem)`.

Comment: @bheklilr I do not have access to the forall syntax. It must be possible to somehow get the first element of the stack in my function?!

Comment: Did you put `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` at the top of your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As two commenters suggested, you need `-XScopedTypeVariables`.

The following code compiles for me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Foo where

import Control.Monad

data Elem = Number Int | Truth Bool deriving Eq

instance Show Elem where
  show (Number i) = show i
  show (Truth b) = show b

class Stack stack where
  push :: a -> stack a -> stack a
  top :: MonadPlus m => stack a -> m (a,stack a)
  empty :: stack a
  isEmpty :: stack a -> Bool

instance Stack [] where
  push a stack = a:stack
  top stack = if isEmpty stack then mzero else return (head stack, tail stack)
  empty = []
  isEmpty stack = if null stack then True else False

step :: forall stack . Stack stack => String -> stack Elem -> Maybe (stack Elem)
step ex st = let e1 = top st :: Maybe (Elem, stack Elem)
                 --a1 = fmap fst e1
                 --e2 = top (fmap snd e1)
                 --a2 = fmap fst e2
             in Nothing
```

I'm not sure what you mean about "not having access to the `forall` syntax", but if you really want to avoid it, you can also write `step` like this:

```
step :: Stack stack => String -> stack Elem -> Maybe (stack Elem)
step ex (st :: stack Elem) = let e1 = top st :: Maybe (Elem, stack Elem)
                 --a1 = fmap fst e1
                 --e2 = top (fmap snd e1)
                 --a2 = fmap fst e2
             in Nothing
```

You'll still need `ScopedTypeVariables` though.